# obtain upload progress in dropbox(ios)

Tags: ios, dropbox

in dropbox i can easily upload my files but when i trying to get progress of my upload(percentage of file uploaded) i fail , i'm using this method that i found in

> restclient,h

it should be working but nothing happen
 :

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadProgress:(CGFloat)progress forFile:(NSString *)destPath from:(NSString *)srcPath {

    NSLog(@"%0.00f",progress);

}
```

i also have been set my class as delegate for restclient and it work fine in other things.

Answer (score 5):

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadProgress:(CGFloat)progress forFile:(NSString *)destPath from:(NSString *)srcPath 
{

    NSLog(@"%.2f",progress); //Correct way to visualice the float

}
```

Comment: This definitely works but the numbers that it produces don't make much sense.

Comment: The numbers make perfect sense to me. The progress varies from 0 to 1. You can translate it by considering 0 as 0% and 1 as 100%. Also, if you are updating any display element, you should enclose the code in a condition that check that the progress value is actually different than the one in the previous call. That's because given the speed of the CPU on the iOS device and the relatively slower speed of the upload, you will notice that the NSLog() will show many duplicate progress values. For those, you can save resource by not re-updating the UI with the same value ... which would be useless.